# Deltaspike Data Repositories in Wildfly 8.2 with JTA and Container Managed Transaction (CMT)

Tags: wildfly, jta, deltaspike

I am using DeltaSpike Data Repositories for the daos in a project that uses JTA datasources. I recently migrated to Wildfly 8.2 and I got some problems with them:

As described in DeltaSpike documentation, I configured  BeanManagedUserTransactionStrategy as my TransactionStrategy, writing `globalAlternatives.org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.spi.transaction.TransactionStrategy =org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.BeanManagedUserTransactionStrategy` into `/META-INF/apache-deltaspike.properties`

With this configuration, consider a `Role`, a `@Repository RoleDao`, a `TestStatelessClass` that inject the RoleDao and print a line, and a resteasy API that inject the service:

**Role.java**

```
@Entity
public class Role implements Serializable {

@Id
private Long id;

@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
private String role;
// ...
}
```

**RoleDao.java**

```
import org.apache.deltaspike.data.api.EntityRepository;
import org.apache.deltaspike.data.api.Repository;
@Repository
@Dependent
public interface RoleDao extends EntityRepository<Role, Long> {

Role findById(long id);
}
```

**TestStatelessClass.java**

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class TestStatelessClass {
    @Inject RoleDao roleDao;

    public TestStatelessClass() {
    }

    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Stateless: Count roles: " + roleDao.count());
    }
}
```

**TestAPI.java**

```
@Path("test")
//@Stateless
public class TestAPI {

    @Inject TestStatelessClass tsc;

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @NoCache
    public List<String> test() throws Exception {

        tsc.execute();

        return null;
    }
}
```

When tsc.execute() is called, the following exception take place:

```
18:39:57,425 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-19) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component TestStatelessClass for method public void example.scheduler.TestStatelessClass.execute(): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
...
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException
...
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:54) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:96) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:370) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:381) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:70) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:121) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:150) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:742) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:840) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:370) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:381) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:70) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:121) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:150) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:742) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:762) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.getReference(ForwardingBeanManager.java:61) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.BeanManagerProxy.getReference(BeanManagerProxy.java:89) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.apache.deltaspike.partialbean.impl.PartialBeanLifecycle.createHandlerInstance(PartialBeanLifecycle.java:133) [deltaspike-partial-bean-module-impl-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.deltaspike.partialbean.impl.PartialBeanLifecycle.create(PartialBeanLifecycle.java:68) [deltaspike-partial-bean-module-impl-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.bean.ImmutableBean.create(ImmutableBean.java:72) [deltaspike-core-api-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:742) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:840) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:370) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:381) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector$1.proceed(DefaultInjector.java:71) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:73) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.StatelessSessionBeanInjector.inject(StatelessSessionBeanInjector.java:58) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ejb.SessionBeanInjectionTarget.inject(SessionBeanInjectionTarget.java:140) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContext.inject(WeldInjectionContext.java:39) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionInterceptor.java:51) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:28)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.java:56) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.java:94) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:273) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 111 more
...
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS014237: Only session and message-driven beans with bean-managed transaction demarcation are allowed to access UserTransaction]
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS014237: Only session and message-driven beans with bean-managed transaction demarcation are allowed to access UserTransaction
```

If instead of a Contained Managed Transaction class, I use a Stateless Bean Managed Transaction class (`@Stateless @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)`), everything works fine, but changing all the classes and control myself the transaction inside the beans would be painful. Do anyone knows the cause of this errors?

Thank you in advance for any help!

PS: I have some of the workarounds https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DELTASPIKE-552 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DELTASPIKE-420 but does not seem valid.

EDIT: Some POM dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <deltaspike.version>1.3.0</deltaspike.version>
</properties>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-data-module-api</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-data-module-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your `apache-deltaspike.properties` to

```
globalAlternatives.org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.spi.transaction.TransactionStrategy=org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.ContainerManagedTransactionStrategy
```

Because you are creating a CMT so you need to specify this transaction strategy.